# Abstracting string slice try index method to all slice types

Tags: go, slice

I have this function for slices of strings:

```
func tryIndex(arr []string, index int, def string) string {
    if index <= len(arr)-1 {
        return arr[index]
    }
    return def
}
```

And I want to abstract it to a type method for slices in general.

```
func (i []interface) TryIndex(index int, def interface) interface {
    if (index <= len(i)-1) {
        return i[index]
    }
    return def
}
```

However this is giving me two errors:

```
prog.go:9: syntax error: unexpected ), expecting {
prog.go:13: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

Where line 9 is the fund declaration line and line 13 is the "return default" line.

What's going on and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Edit: one issue to my original question is also that apparently default is not allowed. I changed that to "def".

Edit: Used @WesFreeman's suggestion and resolved some issues... Now I'm getting this:

```
prog.go:16: invalid receiver type []interface {} ([]interface {} is an unnamed type)
prog.go:27: aArr.TryIndex undefined (type []string has no field or method TryIndex)
prog.go:28: bArr.TryIndex undefined (type []string has no field or method TryIndex)
```

Where the caller function looks roughly like this:

```
aArr := []string{"al", "ba", "ca"} // Arbitrary variable
bArr := []string{"tl", "cl", "rl"} // same
for i := range aArr {
    aR := aArr.TryIndex(i, "00")
    bR := bArr.TryIndex(i, "00")
}
```

Final Edit:

It's totally fine with what I had to begin with just for strings. My question mostly revolved around if it was possible to abstract it to all slice types. If not that's also a totally valid answer!

Comment: `default` is a reserved keyword and may not be used as an identifier: [Keywords](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords).

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that the empty interface is `interface{}`, not just `interface`. So it's expecting curly braces that aren't there.

If you want to accept slices of all types, you will need to declare `i` as `interface{}`, not `[]interface{}`, since a `[]string` can't be assigned to a `[]interface{}`, but anything can be assigned to a `interface{}`. Then you will need to use the reflect package to access the elements.

Your generic function will be of limited use, though, since its return value will need a type assertion to the element type of the slice. `TryIndex` is basically syntactic sugar, but the type assertion will keep it from being very sweet.